# How can I tell what the query that is executing when I do an Advanced Search looks like?

Tags: search, search-results

When I perform an advanced search I would like to see the query that is created based on the criteria I have chosen in the Advanced Search. Is there a way to see the query that is created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `civicrm.settings.php`, you can enable:

```
define('CIVICRM_DEBUG_LOG_QUERY', 1);
```

Then run the "Advanced Search" and look at the output in `files/civicrm/ConfigAndLog/CiviCRM*log*`. This will output for several queries; to avoid accumulation of junk data, you should probably disable the `CIVICRM_DEBUG_LOG_QUERY` after running the query.

There's some more discussion of this and other debugging techniques at http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Debugging+for+developers

Comment: Thank you for the information. I appreciate the assistance.